# FileReader и массив

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть следующий код

```
var images = [];

$(document).on('change', '#images_input', function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(file) {
            return function(e){
                var id = $('.image').length + 1;
                console.log(id);
                var image = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" class="image">';
                $('.images').append(image);
                images[id] = {key: id, value: file}; // проблема здесь :(
            };

        })(this.files[i]);   
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
    }

    console.log(images);
}
```

Если убрать return то работает, но не выводится изображение, если return не убирать, массив получается не тот который мне нужен. К примеру если выбрать 2 файла, то id для первого и второго файла будет одинаковым. В итоге вместо

```
[1: Object, 2: Object]
 1:Object
 2:Object
```

Получааю следующее - при первом выборе файла, массив получается пустой, при втором получается это

```
[1: Object]
1:Object
2:Object
```

Если выбрать 3 файла сразу, а затем еще один, то получаю

```
[1: Object, 4: Object]
 1:Object
 4:Object
```

Вместо

```
[1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object]
  1:Object
  2:Object
  3:Object
  4:Object
```

В дальнейшем, при отправке формы через ajax тоже самое

```
$(document).on("submit", "#form", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      console.log(images); // тоже самое что и выше
})
```

Comment: где объявление images? Так как `onload` асинхронная функция, то вызвав `console.log(images);` сразу после цикла - в консоли покажет только начальное состояние, но так как хром(к примеру) старается показывать актуальные данные - при развороте получаете текущее значение переменной

Comment: images объявляется в самом верху таким образом `var images = [];` Поправил код.

Comment: тогда читайте предыдущий комментарий: в двух словах все работает как и должно, просто выводите до того как отработали загрузки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `onload` выполняется не сразу, а после загрузки файла, то вызов

```
console.log(images);
```

сразу после цикла - покажет в консоли только начальное состояние,
но так как хром(к примеру) старается показывать актуальные данные - при развороте объекта(массива) получаете текущее значение переменной.

Comment: Проблема все таки в чем то еще, т.к. если выбрать к примеру 3 файла, а затем еще один, массив такой получаю
 `[1: Object]
 1:Object
 4:Object`

Вместо

`[1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object]
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object`

Comment: @Гость, читайте ответ внимательнее: это все проблема вывода в неправильном месте, и попытка консоли показать актуальное значение при развороте. Если бы вызывали `console.log` в момент когда **все** onload отработали - то увидели бы в выводе одинаковый результат в раскрытом и не раскрытом состоянии

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Гость, это ничего не меняет, все работает ровно так, как я и сказал. Попробуйте сделать [mcve] который бы демонстрировал проблему

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
$(document).on('change', '#images_input', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    readImageURL(this, function (id, file) {
         console.log(id);                                                                                                                           
         console.log(file); 
         images[id] = {key: id, value: file};                                                                                                                          
    });
});

function readImageURL(input, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(file) {
            return function(e){
                var id = $('.image').length + 1;
                var image = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" class="image">';
                $('.images').append(image);
                callback(id, file);
            };
        })(input.files[i]);   
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: обратите внимание, что `callback` вызовется столько раз сколько будет картинок. То есть если в ваш вариант из вопроса `console.log` переместить после `images[id] = {key: id, value: file};` то результат будет такой же

Comment: у меня не корректно работает вариант, тот что в вопросе,даже при отправке через ajax. Не знаю почему, но если `var id = $('.image').length + 1;` вынести за пределы `return(){}` ключи дублируются и ломается структура массива

Comment: Возможно не совсем понимаю что имеется ввиду, но код из вашего ответа, отличается от кода из, вашего же, вопроса, только тем, что вместо прямого добавления в массив, вызывается функция в которую это добавление перенесено.